# Vanilla DML operations vs DROP, RECREATE, (RE)INSERT - which is more performant?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ddl, dml

Discussing SQL performance with a colleague, and the topic of maintaining our operational data store tables came up. My colleague (who is vastly more experienced than me) maintains that it is quicker to drop a table, recreate it and insert all of its records than it is to perform standard DML operations on the table when updates to the data take place. Being the skeptic I am, and my previous programming background (in R), it seems completely counter intuitive to me.

A single record is approx. 1.6 KB, spread over approx. 50 columns. Records counts vary per business process but the tables range in size with the smallest being around 25000 records and the largest being around 25000000. The typical data loads into the ODS tables, see between 0 and 500 records being created or modified per table per day.

Which option is more performant, keeping a well-indexed table and using vanilla DML operations (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) vs two DML operations (`DROP TABLE`, `CREATE TABLE`) with a single `INSERT` operation?

Comment: `... spread over approx. 50 columns....` That is not a database table. It is a spreadsheet!

Comment: @joop indeed. I hear you, but we're not able to control the extent of these ODS tables. Our source systems have a certain data model (EAV), that we pivot out to create ODS-like tables - because trying to do operational reporting on an EAV data model is suicide. If the client has configured a set of data to have 100 attributes, the table will have *k* + 100 columns, where *k* is some constant (5 if I remember correctly).

Answer (score -1):

If you aren't going to need the table records or need to restore them then the best performance is to truncate the table. It will keep your schema and table definition so you don't have to recreate it, it will delete all your records (though not recoverable) and allow you to then insert all new records. On the insert, your table will be creating a fresh index. Truncate doesn't log the changes making it much more efficient.

Comment: The truncate statement is MINIMALLY logged. The common belief is a misconseption and it is best not to be reproduced. More about the TRUNCATE statement here: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-1930-truncate-table-is-non-logged/

Comment: yes, you are correct. I should have been more specific when I referred to logging. It does not log the individual rows which gives great savings over the delete statement especially on a large table and once committed, it can't be recovered.